# How can I send a message from one controller to another peer controller

Tags: angularjs

I have the following:

```html
<div data-ng-controller="Controller1">
   <div class="button" 
        data-ng-click="action2()">
   </div>
</div>

<div data-ng-controller="Controller2">

</div>
```

```javascript
angular.module('test')
   .controller('QuestionsStatusController1',
    ['$rootScope', '$scope',
    function ($rootScope, $scope) {

    }]);

angular.module('test')
   .controller('QuestionsStatusController2',
    ['$rootScope', '$scope',
    function ($rootScope, $scope) {

         // I need some way to receive the action2()

    }]);
```

Is there a way I can make a click in the HTML of `Controller1` cause a method to fire in `Controller2`. Note that I do not have a parent controller to either of these controllers. That's due to the fact I am using `ui-router`.

Comment: You'll have to `$rootScope.$broadcast` if the controllers don't have a parent/child relationship

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
angular.module('test')
    .controller('QuestionsStatusController1',
    ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$resource', '$state',
    function ($rootScope, $scope, $resource, $state) {

        $scope.action2 = function() {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('action2@QuestionStatusController1');
        }

    }]);

angular.module('test')
   .controller('QuestionsStatusController2',
   ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$resource', '$state',
   function ($rootScope, $scope, $resource, $state) {

    $rootScope.$on('action2@QuestionStatusController1', function {
         //write your listener here
    })

   }]);
```

Comment: This is correct, but make sure to unregister/unsubscribe your listener when your controller gets cleaned up.

Comment: How do I unregister/unsubscribe ?

Comment: @Melina `scope.$on('$destroy', function() { $rootScope.$off('action2@QuestionStatusController1', referenceToYourListenerFunc);})`

Alternatively, `$on` passes back a cleanup function which you can call in the `$destroy` event:
`var cleanUpFunc = $rootScope.$on('action2@QuestionStatusController1', function {
         //write your listener here
    }); $scope.$on('$destroy', function() { cleanUpFunc(); });`
Sorry for the formatting.

Comment: @Polaris878 - This is a little bit confusing to me. I will mark this answer as correct and then open up another question. Can you answer that one to give the code I would need to do the destroy. Thank you.